# How can I replace words in a string with corresponding to the order of a vector?

Tags: r

For example, I have a string:

```
myString <- "a c b c c"
```

and a corresponding vector, it is somehow like a dictionary

```
mylevel <- c("a", "b", "c") # Means "a" is the first one, "b" is the second, "c" is the third.
```

I want to get the new string looks like below:

```
"1 3 2 3 3"
```

How can I do this efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any of these four possibilities should be pretty efficient.  The first one splits the `myString` string on the space then matches it to `mylevel` using `fastmatch::fmatch()`.  Then we paste the results.

```
s <- strsplit(myString, " ", fixed = TRUE)[[1L]]
paste(fastmatch::fmatch(s, mylevel), collapse = " ")
# [1] "1 3 2 3 3"
```

Another idea is to use a lookup vector, like this (using the same `s` from above) -

```
paste(setNames(seq_along(mylevel), mylevel)[s], collapse = " ")
# [1] "1 3 2 3 3"
```

Or this is the same thing, only with `scan()` instead of `strsplit()`.

```
sc <- scan(text = myString, what = "")
paste(setNames(seq_along(mylevel), mylevel)[sc], collapse = " ")
# [1] "1 3 2 3 3"
```

And finally, a fully vectorized replacement courtesy of the *stringi* package.  This should be the most efficient of the four solutions in this answer.

```
library(stringi)
stri_replace_all_fixed(myString, mylevel, seq_along(mylevel), vectorize_all=FALSE)
# [1] "1 3 2 3 3"
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer! But what means [[1L]] after the strsplit()? Does it just means the unlist()?

Comment: Yes, basically that's what it does here.  Since `strsplit` always returns a list we can just subset the first element because we only have one string

Comment: It's really amazing, so many methods I never heard! I am still confused about the `stri_replace_all_fixed()`, you didn't say sep=" ", but the function looks like know the "blank" is the separate. Why?

Comment: @xirururu - That function is a character replacement function.  It is taking `myString`, looking for `mylevel`, and replacing with `seq_along(mylevel)` (because a = 1, b = 2, etc).  So there is no pasting there, it's all done internally.  The stringi package is quite amazing, I recommend everyone to check it out!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it with base R with `match`:

```
sp <-unlist(strsplit(myString, " "))
match(sp,mylevel)
#[1] 1 3 2 3 3
```

If you want it in a string:

```
paste(match(sp,mylevel), collapse=" ")
#[1] "1 3 2 3 3"
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not find it necessary to use `mylevel` for this particular example, although one might have needed to add that vector as a levels argumetn to factor if the levels were not sorted lexically:

```
> paste( as.numeric(factor(scan(text=myString, what="")) ), collapse=" " )
Read 5 items
[1] "1 3 2 3 3"
```

Comment: Or even `paste(factor(scan(text=myString, what=""), labels = 1:3), collapse=" ")` making use of the `labels` arg.  Then coercing to numeric doesn't matter as they will both be the same

Answer (score 0):

```
  str_new <-''
    for (i in strsplit(myString," ")[[1]]){
         str_new <- paste(str_new,which(mylevel==i))

     }
```

Comment: oh yes forgot to add :(